# Issue with GET form php/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to build a dynamic site. I have an input form across the top that when it has been submitted show the output from an asynchronous request to a  PHP page (which utilizes `echo`), showing what was submitted.

However it is not working. I submit it and the whole form disappears (this should not be happening either). I am at my wits ends with getting it to work and I can not seem to figure out what I am missing. Can anyone explain why it is not working as desired?

I am having trouble with the code page *DomainDiagnostics.php*. Excuse the bare bones- eventually I plan to populate the divs with AJAX calls to functions, but A.T.M. I just want it to echo out the input, and keep the Input form at the top...

Code - Index.php

```
</head>
<body>
<!--- This Keeps the navbar from staying right near top -->
<div class="header">
</div>

<!---- Nav bar, Using bootstrap ----->
<nav class="navbar navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="nav-bar-logo">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-left"><img src="cwcs-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="nav-list-container">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a id="dd" href="#">Domain Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li><a id="sd" href="#">Server Diagnostics</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Second Line Tools
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a id="dc" href="#">Daily Checklist</a></li>
          <li><a id="bt" href="#">Backup Tracker</a></li>
          <li><a id="tl" href="#">Task List</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!------- End of nav bar ---->


<!----- All content is initally loaded into this page-container --->
<div id="page-container">



</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Javascript - this loads the pages depending on which Button the Nav is clicked. I have only actually done the domain diagnostic page,

```
// Executes when document is ready
$(document).ready(function($)
{


// On click divs for the navigation bar that load the different views (pages)
$( "#dd" ).click(function() 
  {
      $("#page-container").load("./views/domaindiagnostics.php"); 
  });

$( "#sd" ).click(function() 
  {
      $("#page-container").load("./views/serverdiagnostics.php"); 
  });

$( "#dc" ).click(function() 
  {
      $("#page-container").load("./views/dailychecklist.php"); 
  });

$( "#bt" ).click(function() 
  {
    $("#page-container").load("./views/backuptracker.php"); 
  });

$( "#tl" ).click(function() 
  {
    $("#page-container").load("./views/tasklist.php"); 
  });

// end of nav bar   

});
```

Domain Diagnostics page, so the input form shows as expected, but this is the bit thats not working

```
<?php
/// Grabs the domainclass php file and also grabs the users input and places in $domainName variable
require '../php/domainclass.php';
if (isset($_GET['userInput'])) 
{
    $domainName = $_GET['userInput'];
 echo $domainName;
}

?>
<form class="form">
<div class="domainquery">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input id="domainName" name="userInput" class="form-control input-md" type="text" placeholder="aaexamddple.org" value="<?php if (isset($domainName)) echo $domainName ?>" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Query Domain</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>


<div class="domain-d-container">


</div>


</div> 

<script>

            $(document).ready(function() 
            {

          $( ".form" ).submit(function() 
          {

                 $(".domain-d-container").load("domaindiagnosticsresults.php", 
                 {
                                        d: "<?php echo $domainName ?>"
                                    });


          });

            });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

domaindiangosticsresults.php

```
<?php

$domainName = $_POST['d'];
echo $domainName;
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't $domainName = 'userInput'; be $domainName = $_GET['userInput']; ?
Also, a $_GET would look for a parameter like index.php?userInput=somevalue

Comment: Where is the `ajax` call?

Comment: @nerdlyist it's the jquery `load()` functions.

Comment: Oh so the issue is when you click a `nav` link you want to refresh the `#page-container` but leave the form at the top.

Comment: can you specify _" but this is the bit thats not working"_? What exactly do you expect, that does not happen that way?

Comment: your problem is, that once you submit the form (which you've just inserted via 'load') the page sends this form to `index.php` - _NOT_ to `domainDiagnostics.php`. It's a design problem. Seperate the view (the form) from the actual data-fetching - do that also via ajax.

Comment: When you submit the form, your index.php will reload. When it does, the Domain Diagnostics page will not be loaded anymore, because of that the form disappeared. You could use ajax to submit the form

Comment: Updated post with new code.  What I want is for when i submit the form for domain-d-container to be populated with the users input (and for the nav bar and the input to remain on the page).  Currently the form input still disapears.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is what you need inside `submit(function(event) { ...}`

Comment: still, this is no good design. You'll get in even more troubles when sticking on this. Please seperate your logic from view and data.

Comment: Is it because I am trying to build the whole thing in ajax, would I be best of normal hyper linking to DomainDiagnostics, and then using ajax inside of that?  I was trying to avoid having to copy and paste the nav bar ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

The form disappears because when the user clicks the button labeled *Query Domain*, the form is submitted. Because the form has no *action* method, it basically reloads index.php.

#### Changes

As have been pointed out in comments, there are a few things that need to be changed in order to get it *working*:

- in the form submission handler - prevent the default form submission by either

  - calling [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event object (i.e. `e` in the example below), which is passed to the callback function:

    ```
    $( ".form" ).submit(function(e) 
    {
      //stop form submission
      e.preventDefault();
    ```
  - returning false at the end of the function
- pass the value of the input to the diagnostics results by appending it to the query string (e.g. use jQuery's [$.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)):

  ```
  $(".domain-d-container").load("domaindiagnosticsresults.php", 
  {
      d: $('#domainName').val()
  ```
- there was an excess closing div tag (i.e. `</div>`) that should be removed after `<div class="domain-d-container"></div>` in the domaindiagnostics.php page.
- The (closing) `</html>` and `</body>` tags should be removed from the nested pages (e.g. *domaindiagnostics.php*), lest those tags exist as child tags of the body of the index page (those would not be permitted content of a [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) - only [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) is allowed).

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/64cy-hgrx). Bear in mind that only one PHP page is allowed in that environment so I had to combine the three pages and use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for the URLs and pass data via the query string, so some of the checks on `$_POST` were converted to checks on `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link con help you. https://dailygit.com/create-a-simple-ajax-contact-form-with-jquery-and-php/

Remove the "send mail" part and focus on the form submission part. as said in other comments, prevent default is really important and the DOM structure must be cleaner as possible.